# Kivy Nested ScreenManager inside BoxLayout

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

Something seen with a different flavor each week, Here we go again with more ScreenManager shenanigans!

Screens won't change unless buttons are part of the screen itself, I wanted a universal navbar along the top and then a "display" under it. Both screens work, the buttons to switch between them don't.

(Bonus points if you can tell me how to make each screen its own KV file and still link with the screenmanager)

anyways: CODE

QCManager.py

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, NoTransition

kivy.require('1.9.1')


class MOTD(Screen):
    print("MOTD Screen!")
    pass


class Search(Screen):
    print("Search Screen!")
    pass


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


class ClassAllScreen(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.manager = ScreenManagement()


class ClassApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = ClassAllScreen()
        return self.root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Builder.load_file('./kvfiles/main.kv')
    ClassApp().run()
```

main.kv

```
#: import NoTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.NoTransition
<MOTD>:
    name: 'motd'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        padding:20
        spacing:10
        Label:
            text:"The Cake Is a Lie"

<Search>:
    name: 'search'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        padding:20
        spacing:10
        GridLayout:
            spacing:10
            cols:2

            Button:
                text:'Left'
            Button:
                text:'Right'
        Button:
            text:'bottom'


<ScreenManagement>:
    transition: NoTransition()
    MOTD:
    Search:

<ClassAllScreen>:
    orientation:'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 60
        spacing: 5
        padding: 5

        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: .1,.1,.1,1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        Button:
            text:'Menu'
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 120
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'motd'
        Button:
            text:'Search'
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 120
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'search'
        Button:
            text:'Add to DB'
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 120
            on_press: print("Button Working")
    ScreenManagement:
```

Comment: Edit: found the github Snippets page from a different link, didn't know it existed. https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Linking-ScreenManager-to-a-different-Widget might fix my issue, not near my computer to test it rn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `__init__()` method in the `ClassAllScreen` class is creating an instance of `ScreenManagement`. That instance is saved as `self.manager`, but is not added to your GUI.

In your `kv` file, the line:

```
ScreenManagement:
```

is creating another, different instance of `ScreenManagement`. This instance of `ScreenManagement` is the one that is in your GUI.

So anything your do to `self.manager` in the `ClassAllScreen` will have no effect on the `ScreenManagement` that is in your GUI.

The fix is to make sure you are referencing the correct instance of `ScreenManagement` (and not bother to create any other instances). To do this you can add an `ObjectProperty` to `ClassAllScreen` in the `kv` file, like this:

```
<ClassAllScreen>:
    manager: scr_manager  # added ObjectProperty that references the scr_manager id
    orientation:'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 60
        spacing: 5
        padding: 5

        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: .1,.1,.1,1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        Button:
            text:'Menu'
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 120
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'motd'
        Button:
            text:'Search'
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 120
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'search'
        Button:
            text:'Add to DB'
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 120
            on_press: print("Button Working")
    ScreenManagement:
        id: scr_manager  # new id to enable reference to this ScreenManagement instance
```

And the `ClassAllScreen` class can then be simplified to:

```
class ClassAllScreen(BoxLayout):
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to make another small modification to your code to get it to work but it was as easy as adding the MOTD and Search screens to the scr_manager in the .kv file (since I removed the reference to it above in my code) Accepting the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Just to help out anyone trying to do the same. The fixed code is below

App.py

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, NoTransition

kivy.require('1.9.1')


class MOTD(Screen):
    print("MOTD Screen!")
    pass


class Search(Screen):
    print("Search Screen!")
    pass


# class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    # pass  # Removed, Instanced in kv


class ClassAllScreen(BoxLayout):
    pass  # Removed code, Done in kv


class ClassApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = ClassAllScreen()
        return self.root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Builder.load_file('./kvfiles/main.kv')
    ClassApp().run()
```

main.kv

```
#: import NoTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.NoTransition
<MOTD>:
    name: 'motd'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        padding:20
        spacing:10
        Label:
            text:"The Cake Is a Lie"

<Search>:
    name: 'search'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        padding:20
        spacing:10
        GridLayout:
            spacing:10
            cols:2

            Button:
                text:'Left'
            Button:
                text:'Right'
        Button:
            text:'bottom'


<ClassAllScreen>:
    manager:scr_manager
    orientation:'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 60
        spacing: 5
        padding: 5

        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: .1,.1,.1,1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        Button:
            text:'Menu'
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 120
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'motd'
        Button:
            text:'Search'
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 120
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'search'
        Button:
            text:'Add to DB'
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 120
            on_press: print("Button Working")
    ScreenManager:
        transition: NoTransition()
        id: scr_manager
        MOTD:
        Search:
```